# Upgrading to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition and Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1607

After updating from Windows 10 to the Anniversary Update (build 1607), I experienced issues with Hyper-V. I was not able to start my virtual machines.

An error message was:

> Export failed for virtual machine 'name' (guid) with error 'A
>   virtual disk support provider for the specified file was not found.'
>   (0xC03A0014).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my troubleshooting steps, I recommend the following steps to reduce the upgrade pain.

> Note: Since I already updated Windows 10 before getting into trouble, I was not able to test this in this order, so your feedback is important.

**Before the update**

1. Shutdown all Hyper-V virtual machines.
2. Go to Start > Turn Windows Features on or off.
3. Uncheck Hyper-V and confirm the reboot question.

**Update Windows**

- Update to Windows 10 Anniversary Edition, [you can force this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history). Note that you have control of when you start the download, however, once the download was done I was not able to postpone the actual update.

**After the Windows update**

1. Go to Start > Turn Windows Features on or off.
2. Check Hyper-V and confirm the reboot question.
3. After the reboot, start Hyper-V Manager
4. Hyper-V Manager > Your virtual machine(s) > Right-click to update configuration version.
5. Hyper-V Manager > Go to Virtual Switch Manager to re-create your virtual LAN and/or WIFI devices.
6. In your VM configuration, configure the network device from the previous step.

Comment: what you propose here is to re-install the Hyper-v and not an actually solution to the problem. I have similar problems with Hyper-v, its not work to me any more after the anniversary update of windows 10. I have made many to make it work again, and this one to re-install it, but NOT, its not work any more...

Comment: Hey @Aristos, you are right that this is a workaround for the problem. I shared the problem and workaround in the hope that other people can save time and to hear if this also occurs for them. If it is a recurring problem a fix in Windows 10 itself might be the real solution.

Answer (score -1):

This Anniversary update is defective and has many issues with hyper-v the solution to this post is to introduce a line on the BCDBoot using the following command:

```
BCDEDIT /Set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

But there are other problems with this particular version of Windows 10 so I recommend that you stay in version 1106 until it gets fixed

Comment: There is no such thing as Version 1106...